# Foreign key nil when creating multiple nested associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my application I have the following 4 models:

`App`, `AppPortal`, `AppPortalVersion`, and `AppPortalConfiguration`.

Which are associated as follows:

```
class App < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :apps
  has_one :app_portal, class_name: 'AppPortal'
end

class AppPortal < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :app_portals
  belongs_to :app, class_name: 'App'
  has_many :app_portal_versions,
           class_name: 'AppPortalVersion',
           foreign_key: :app_portal_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_portal_versions
end

class AppPortalVersion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :app_portal_versions
  belongs_to :app_portal,
              class_name: 'AppPortal',
              foreign_key: :app_portal_id
  has_one :app_portal_configuration,
          class_name: 'AppPortalConfiguration',
          foreign_key: :app_portal_version_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_portal_configuration
end

class AppPortalConfiguration < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :app_portal_configurations
  belongs_to :app_portal_version,
             class_name: 'AppPortalVersion',
             foreign_key: :app_portal_version_id
end
```

I've added the `table_name` and `foreign_key` to be explicit for both the question and to make sure Rails is aware of what model talks to what, etc.

Now I want to create these nested associations for an existing app like so:

```
app = App.first
app_portal = app.build_app_portal
app_portal_version = app_portal.app_portal_versions.build
app_portal_version.build_app_portal_configuration
app_portal.save!
```

However if print the objects for each model, I see that only the `app_portal` is correctly associated with the `App` and the other objects whilst correctly associated, have the foreign key values set as `nil` which causes the final `save!` to fail.

```
puts app_portal
=> #<AppPortal:0x000000011bc6d420 id: nil, app_id: 18>

puts app_portal_version
=> #<AppPortalVersion:0x000000011b3658c8 id: nil, app_portal_id: nil>

puts app_portal_version.app_portal_configuration
=> #<AppPortalConfiguration:0x000000012fb264e0 id: nil, app_portal_version_id: nil>
```

As you can see the association id's are `nil` which will then cause this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: App portal versions app portal must exist, App portal versions app portal configuration app portal version must exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the extra options that you're setting are rails defaults and don't change anything. It actually makes it a bit worse. Rails docs don't go out of their way to say why, but:

> `:foreign_key` Specify the foreign key used for the association. By
> default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and
> `_id` suffixed. So a Person class that makes a `has_one` association
> will use `person_id` as the default `:foreign_key`.
>
> **If you are going to modify the association (rather than just read from
> it), then it is a good idea to set the `:inverse_of` option.**

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

You have two validation errors:

```
# App portal versions app portal must exist
>> app_portal_version.app_portal
=> nil

# App portal versions app portal configuration app portal version must exist
>> app_portal_version.app_portal_configuration.app_portal_version
=> nil
```

Sure don't exist. To make it a bit clearer:

```
>> app_portal_version = AppPortalVersion.new
>> app_portal_version.app_portal_configuration = AppPortalConfiguration.new
# but if you go through association on the other side, aka inverse,
# nothing is assigned, which makes configuration model invalid
>> app_portal_version.app_portal_configuration.app_portal_version
>> nil
```

Note that when you call `build` and `build_app_portal` methods you're just making new model instances, they don't have an `id`, so `foreign_key`s can only be set after everything is saved into the database. `App.first` already has an id so `app_portal` gets a foreign key `app_id: 18`.

If `:foreign_key` option is set, rails will give up trying to guess an inverse association:

> Checks to see if the reflection doesn't have any options that prevent us from being able to guess the inverse automatically. First, the `inverse_of` option cannot be set to false. Second, we must have `has_many`, `has_one`, `belongs_to` associations. Third, we must not have options such as `:foreign_key` which prevent us from correctly guessing the inverse association.

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L650-L661*

You can verify it in the console:

```rb
# this is a lazily loaded option, so you have to call it explicitly or it had
# to be called by rails before to be loaded
>> AppPortalVersion.reflect_on_association(:app_portal_configuration).inverse_of
=> nil
```

With your current models you can add `:inverse_of` option:

```
class AppPortalVersion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :app_portal_versions
  belongs_to :app_portal, class_name: "AppPortal", foreign_key: :app_portal_id
  has_one :app_portal_configuration,
    class_name: "AppPortalConfiguration",
    foreign_key: :app_portal_version_id,
    inverse_of: :app_portal_version       # <= like this
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_portal_configuration
end
```

```
>> AppPortalVersion.reflect_on_association(:app_portal_configuration).inverse_of
=> 
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x00007f5b96a40238
 @active_record=AppPortalConfiguration(id: integer, app_portal_version_id: integer),
 @klass=nil,
 @name=:app_portal_version,
 @options={:class_name=>"AppPortalVersion", :foreign_key=>:app_portal_version_id},
 @plural_name="app_portal_versions",
 @scope=nil>

# now it works in reverse
>> app_portal_version = AppPortalVersion.new(app_portal_configuration: AppPortalConfiguration.new)
>> app_portal_version.app_portal_configuration.app_portal_version
=> #<AppPortalVersion:0x00007f574c1236a8 id: nil, app_portal_id: nil>
```

This would be the default setup that just works without any extra options, inverse associations are automatically detected:

```rb
class App < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :app_portal, dependent: :destroy # < maybe one option you actually need
end

class AppPortal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :app_portal_versions, dependent: :destroy
  # NOTE: unrelated to the issue, i assume you use it elsewhere
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_portal_versions
end

class AppPortalVersion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app_portal
  has_one :app_portal_configuration, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_portal_configuration
end

class AppPortalConfiguration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app_portal_version
end
```

```rb
>> AppPortal.create!(app: App.first, app_portal_versions_attributes: [{app_portal_configuration_attributes: {} }] )
# ...
=> #<AppPortal:0x00007f079ef87580 id: 7, app_id: 1>
```

You don't need any extra options, unless you're dropping `app_` and `app_portal_` prefixes, which could be nice:

```rb
class App < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :portal, class_name: "AppPortal", dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :portal
end
class AppPortal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :versions, class_name: "AppPortalVersion", inverse_of: :portal, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :versions
end
class AppPortalVersion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portal, class_name: "AppPortal", foreign_key: :app_portal_id
  has_one :configuration, class_name: "AppPortalConfiguration", inverse_of: :version, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configuration
end
class AppPortalConfiguration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :version, class_name: "AppPortalVersion", foreign_key: :app_portal_version_id
end
```

```rb
>> App.create!(portal_attributes: {versions_attributes: [{configuration_attributes: {}}]})
=> #<App:0x00007f6a32bf7450 id: 8>

# deep nested attributes can be a pain so this works too
>> App.create!(portal: AppPortal.new(versions: [AppPortalVersion.new(configuration: AppPortalConfiguration.new)]))
=> #<App:0x00007f6a32cc9388 id: 9>

>> App.last.portal.versions.last.configuration
=> #<AppPortalConfiguration:0x00007f6a32862a88 id: 11, app_portal_version_id: 11>
```